# Why does UpsertDe fail with Subscriber ID?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I have an odd bug that I am running into. I will try to explain what we are seeing as best as possible without writing a novel! What we are trying to do is run a bit of AMPscript to add/update a record to a data extension within our instance. When we use the InsertDE function, the subscriber id writes to the mentioned table below (sub_id_reference_prod). This function works fine at time of send.

I then used the @sub_id_update value to make sure something was available to populate if we were to use the upsertde function. This too worked.

Now when I add these components together with the UpsertDe function, the Upsert call does not add subscriber id to the referenced table.

I have tried multiple variations and nothing adds the subscriber id using the upsert function. Is there a limitation with the UpsertDe function that doesn't allow a subscriber id update?

```
set @subscriberid = subscriberid
set @email_address = emailaddr
set @value = 'true'
set @subkey = SubscriberKey
InsertDE('sub_id_reference_prod','email_address',@email_address, 'subscriberid',@subscriberid)

set @sub_id_count = LookUpRows('sub_id_reference_prod','email_address',@email_address)

if rowcount(@sub_id_count) > 0 then
set @sub_id_update = 

LookUp('sub_id_reference_prod','subscriberid','email_address',@email_address)
UpsertDE('ent.mbusa_contact_master_de',1,'subscriber_key',@subscriberkey,'email_address',@email_address,'subscriberid',@sub_id_update)
endif
```

Comment: I can't see where you are setting the value for @subscriberkey in the upsert function?

Comment: Is there an error? Have you verified that it does write to the DE, just not the SubID? I also would remove the new lines separating `set @sub_id_update =` from the following Lookup() statement. I find that new lines inside of AMPScript variable setting can cause some odd behaviors at times.

Comment: It does write to the DE, but the Sub id isn't there when the update occurs. The new line is a formatting issue with SE. The content block has the function on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a value for your lookup.

`set @lookupvariable = LookUp('sub_id_reference_prod','subscriberid','email_address',@email_address)`